# Confusion on how to finish a new program?

Tags: java

I am currently doing a project for my java class and im a total beginner so apologies because i'm sure the answer is quite obvious. A few weeks back I made a program called TravelExpenses which calculated how much a trip would cost. Now, I must make a new program that is completely different. After coding and pressing play, The same window pops up from my previous program, how do I get rid of it? [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJByg.jpg)

Comment: Don't press "play". Right click on your new program and then click "Run As" then "java"

Comment: Your run configuration probably still points to the old main method

Answer (score -1):

In the package explorer, right click your new class and choose run as.. java program

The next time you press play it will launch the recent one.